# Chameleon template looping

Tags: python, chameleon, template-tal

I tried to create template using chameleon. Here is a code snipet.

Calling module `runtemp.py`:

```
delete_list=[]
delete={'Name':'aaa','Sirname':'bbb','Friends':['ccc','ddd','eee']}
delete_list.append(delete)
templates = PageTemplateLoader(os.path.join(path, "templates"))
template = templates["delete_user.pt"]
print template(tdelete_list=delete_list)
```

Template file `delete_list.pt`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Delete>
   <DeleteRequest>

       <DeleteItems tal:repeat="deletions tdelete_list">

           <Deleteuser tal:repeat="delete repeat.deletions" >

                <Name tal:content="repeat.delete.Name"></Name>
                <Sirname tal:content="repeat.delete.Sirname"></Sirname>
                 <Friends>
                      <Friend tal:repeat="friend repeat.delete.Friends">
                               <Value tal:content="friend"></Value>
                       </Friend>
                 </Friends>

           </Deleteuser>

     <DeleteItems>

    </DeleteRequest>

 </Delete>
```

Output i got:

```
 <Delete>
        <DeleteRequest>

           <DeleteItems>



           </DeleteItems>
  </DeleteRequest>
 </Delete>
```

My problem is the middle tags are not getting printed; what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `<DeleteItems tal:repeat="deletions tdelete_list">` means to loop over `tdelete_list` and put each element in the variable `deletions`.

Thus, your inner loop just needs to loop over `deletions`; the `repeat.` prefix is *not* used here:

```
<Deleteuser tal:repeat="delete deletions" >

    <Name tal:content="delete.Name"></Name>
    <Sirname tal:content="delete.Sirname"></Sirname>
     <Friends>
          <Friend tal:repeat="friend delete.Friends">
                   <Value tal:content="friend"></Value>
           </Friend>
     </Friends>

</Deleteuser>
```

The `repeat.deletions` variable is actually only used to store loop metadata; the current count, the `first` and `last` flags, the `odd` and `even` flags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `tdelete_list` which is a list with one element (the dict you create in line 2). That's how you get that one `<DeleteItems />` tag. Within that tag, you try to iterate over `repeat.deletions`, however in the context you pass to the template, there's no object named `repeat.deletions`.

I guess from your variable naming that you're misinterpreting what `tal:repeat="deletions tdelete_list"` does - it iterates over `tdelete_list` and assigns the name `deletions` to each element of that iterable in turn. Inside the `<DeleteItems />` tag, you can access that element under that name.